# XSLT to remove line feeds in the XML

Tags: xml, xslt

The output xml of the below xsl has line feeds. I need to remove the line feeds  in the cteDadosMsg node in the below xsl map.

XSL Map

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap12:Header>
            <cteCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte/wsdl/CteConsulta">
                <cUF><xsl:value-of select="substring(/n0:ConsultaCT/n0:chCTe,1,2)"/></cUF>
                <versaoDados>2.00</versaoDados>
            </cteCabecMsg>
        </soap12:Header>
        <soap12:Body>
            <cteDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte/wsdl/CteConsulta">
                <consSitCTe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="3.10">
                    <tpAmb><xsl:value-of select="/n0:ConsultaCT/n0:tpAmb"/></tpAmb>
                    <xServ>CONSU</xServ>
                    <chCTe><xsl:value-of select="/n0:ConsultaCT/n0:chCTe"/></chCTe>
                </consSitCTe>
            </cteDadosMsg>
        </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output**

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried it to see if it works since I dont have your XML but I think the reason you are getting line feed is that you are using static strings 2.00 and CONSU and static strings come with a line feed. You might want to give a try by replacing these static strings with xsl:text to see if you still get line feeds...
Some thing like

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <soap12:Header>
              <cteCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte/wsdl/CteConsulta">
                <cUF><xsl:value-of select="substring(/n0:ConsultaCT/n0:chCTe,1,2)"/></cUF>
                <versaoDados><xsl:text>2.00</xsl:text></versaoDados>
           </cteCabecMsg>
        </soap12:Header>
        <soap12:Body>
            <cteDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte/wsdl/CteConsulta">
                 <consSitCTe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="3.10">
                    <tpAmb><xsl:value-of select="/n0:ConsultaCT/n0:tpAmb"/></tpAmb>
                    <xServ><xsl:text>CONSU</xsl:text></xServ>
                    <chCTe><xsl:value-of select="/n0:ConsultaCT/n0:chCTe"/></chCTe>
                  </consSitCTe>
              </cteDadosMsg>
           </soap12:Body>
       </soap12:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
```